# Spark ERROR executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (tid 0) java.lang.ArithmeticException

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector

I got the error bellow when I ran an application Java Web using Cassandra 3.11.9 and Spark 3.0.1.

My question is why  did it happen only after deploy the application? In the development environment it did not occur.

> 2021-03-24 08:50:41.150 INFO 19613 --- [uler-event-loop]
> org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler : ShuffleMapStage 0
> (collectAsList at FalhaService.java:60) failed in 7.513 s due to Job
> aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 1 times, most
> recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0) (GDBHML08 executor
> driver): java.lang.ArithmeticException: integer overflow at
> java.lang.Math.toIntExact(Math.java:1011) at
> org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.util.DateTimeUtils$.fromJavaDate(DateTimeUtils.scala:90)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.CatalystTypeConverters$DateConverter$.toCatalystImpl(CatalystTypeConverters.scala:306)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.CatalystTypeConverters$DateConverter$.toCatalystImpl(CatalystTypeConverters.scala:305)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.CatalystTypeConverters$CatalystTypeConverter.toCatalyst(CatalystTypeConverters.scala:107)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.CatalystTypeConverters$StructConverter.toCatalystImpl(CatalystTypeConverters.scala:252)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.CatalystTypeConverters$StructConverter.toCatalystImpl(CatalystTypeConverters.scala:242)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.CatalystTypeConverters$CatalystTypeConverter.toCatalyst(CatalystTypeConverters.scala:107)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.CatalystTypeConverters$.$anonfun$createToCatalystConverter$2(CatalystTypeConverters.scala:426)
> at
> com.datastax.spark.connector.datasource.UnsafeRowReader.read(UnsafeRowReaderFactory.scala:34)
> at
> com.datastax.spark.connector.datasource.UnsafeRowReader.read(UnsafeRowReaderFactory.scala:21)
> at
> com.datastax.spark.connector.datasource.CassandraPartitionReaderBase.$anonfun$getIterator$2(CassandraScanPartitionReaderFactory.scala:110)
> at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.next(Iterator.scala:461) at
> scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:496) at
> com.datastax.spark.connector.datasource.CassandraPartitionReaderBase.next(CassandraScanPartitionReaderFactory.scala:66)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.PartitionIterator.hasNext(DataSourceRDD.scala:79)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.MetricsIterator.hasNext(DataSourceRDD.scala:112)
> at
> org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:37)
> at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:460) at
> org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1.agg_doAggregateWithKeys_0$(Unknown
> Source) at
> org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1.processNext(Unknown
> Source) at
> org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:755)
> at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:460) at
> org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.write(BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.java:132)
> at
> org.apache.spark.shuffle.ShuffleWriteProcessor.write(ShuffleWriteProcessor.scala:59)
> at
> org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:99)
> at
> org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:52)
> at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:131) at
> org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:497)
> at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1439)
> at
> org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:500)
> at
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
> at
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
>
> Driver stacktrace: 2021-03-24 08:50:41.189 INFO 19613 ---
> [nio-8080-exec-2] org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler : Job 0
> failed: collectAsList at FalhaService.java:60, took 8.160348 s

The line's code that it is in this error:

```
List<Row> rows = dataset.collectAsList();
```

The code's block:

```
Dataset<Row> dataset = session.sql(sql.toString());

List<Row> rows = dataset.collectAsList();
ListIterator<Row> t = rows.listIterator();
while (t.hasNext()) {
    Row row = t.next();
    grafico = new EstGraficoRelEstTela();
    grafico.setSuperficie(row.getLong(0));
    grafico.setSubsea(row.getLong(1) + row.getLong(2));
    grafico.setNomeTipoSensor(row.getString(3));
    graficoLocalFalhas.add(grafico);
}
session.close();
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like that you have incorrect data in the database, some date field that is far into the future. If you look into the [source code](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v3.0.1/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/util/DateTimeUtils.scala#L111), you can see that it's converting first into milliseconds, and then converting into days, and this conversion overflows the integer.   And this may explain why the code works in dev environment...

You may ask your administrator to check files for corrupted data, for example, using the [nodetool scrub](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/5.1/dse-admin/datastax_enterprise/tools/nodetool/toolsScrub.html) command.

P.S. are you sure that you're using Spark 3.0.1? The location of the function in the error is matching the Spark 3.1.1...

Comment: Thanks a lot. That was the poit. The incorrect data in the field date. I corrected the date at the table and the error was fixed. I was using the spark 3.0.1 as the maven dependecy. Now I changed to `<version>3.1.1</version>` .

Comment: Be careful with that. 3.1.1 contains a breaking change, so some optimizations, like DirectJoin will crash. 3.1 will require a new release of the connector to fix that

Comment: Ok, @Alex Ott. I changed all the dependency and it was function. However all still pay attention. Thanks.